# Concatenation of fields in different rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a query in mysql that it's result is as below:

```
val1_col1A  val1_col2A  val1_col1B val1_col2B
val1_col1A  val1_col2A  val2_col1B val2_col2B
val1_col1A  val1_col2A  val3_col1B val3_col2B
```

like this :

```
1 reza math 20
1 reza c++  19
1 reza C#   17
```

my query is :

```
SELECT col1A,col2A,col1B,col2B
FROM  A join B
ON col3A=col3B
```

I want to have a query that it result be as below :

```
val1_col1A  val1_col2A  val1_col1B,val2_col1B,val3_col1B val1_col2B,val2_col2B,val3_col2B
```

Like this :

```
1 reza math,c++,c# 20,19,17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT val1_col1A), 
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT val1_col2A), 
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT val1_col1B),
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT val1_col2B)) AS value
FROM table_name;
```